# Why do I get a small window titled 'Tk' when my code is run?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

style = ttk.Style()

def main():
    global MainMenu
    global style
    MainMenu = Toplevel()
    MainMenu.title('Rubiks Cube Solver')  # Creates a window with the title 'Rubiks Cube Solver' that is 640x480 and with a gray background
    MainMenu.geometry('640x480')
    MainMenu.config(bg='gray')

    style.configure('W.TButton', font=('Consolas', 25), foreground = 'black')  # Style for the buttons

    
    Label(MainMenu, text='Rubiks Cube Solver', font=('Consolas', 40, 'bold'), bg='gray').pack()  # Shows a title 'Rubiks Cube Solver'
    
    timerbtn = ttk.Button(MainMenu, text='Timer', style='W.TButton')
    timerbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)   # Creates a button and anchors it to the center
    
    solverbtn = ttk.Button(MainMenu, text='Solver', style='W.TButton')
    solverbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)  
    
    databasebtn = ttk.Button(MainMenu, text='Database', style='W.TButton', command=maindatabase)
    databasebtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)

def maindatabase():
    MainMenu.withdraw()
    DataMenu = Toplevel(MainMenu)
    DataMenu.title('Database Viewer')  # Creates a window with the title 'Database Viewer' that is 640x480 and with a gray background
    DataMenu.geometry('640x480')
    DataMenu.config(bg='gray')

    
    Label(DataMenu, text='Database Viewer', font=('Consolas', 40, 'bold'), bg='gray').pack()  # Shows a title 'Database Viewer'

    
    searchbtn = ttk.Button(DataMenu, text='Search', style='W.TButton')
    searchbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)   # Creates a button and anchors it to the center
    
    fullbtn = ttk.Button(DataMenu, text='Full View', style='W.TButton')
    fullbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER)  
    
    backbtn = ttk.Button(DataMenu, text='Back', command=lambda:[DataMenu.destroy(), MainMenu.deiconify()])
    backbtn.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`
```

When this code is run, it opens the desired main menu and a small white window called **Tk**.

When I define `MainMenu = Tk()` instead of `Toplevel()`, none of my buttons have any styling. If I put the styling in the `main()` function, then the second window has no button styling. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to explicitly call `Tk()` yourself, so that you have a reference to the root window and can control it.  If you don't, the first Tk function you call (this would be `style = ttk.Style()` in your case) creates a root window for you, which you can't easily do anything with because you have no reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

### There are two issues in this code example.

1. In **tkinter**, it is a good practice to create one "[Main Window](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules)" `Tk()`, and then you can use as many "[Dialogs](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/toplevel.html)" `Toplevel()` as you want.
2. "[Style](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html)" `ttk.Style()` component requires the "[Main Window](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules)" `Tk()` to already be created, if it's not, like in your case, "[Style](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html)" `ttk.Style()` creates its own "[Main Window](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules)" `Tk()`, and that is the **reason** you have **two windows** in your example.

---

### Quick Solution:

1. Change this line: `MainMenu = Toplevel()` to `MainMenu = Tk()`, and add `MainMenu.mainloop()` at the end of the `main()` function
2. Comment out this line: `style = ttk.Style()`, and add it to the `main()` function right after the `MainMenu = Tk()`

---

### Personal Recommendation: (OOP approach)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#style = ttk.Style()

class RCS():
    def __init__(self):
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        self.MainWindow = Tk()
        self.style = ttk.Style() # Declare the Style here, and you can use it later on Dialogs as well

        self.MainWindow.title('Rubiks Cube Solver')  # Creates a window with the title 'Rubiks Cube Solver' that is 640x480 and with a gray background
        self.MainWindow.geometry('640x480')
        self.MainWindow.config(bg='gray')
        #style.configure('W.TButton', font=('Consolas', 25), foreground = 'black')  # Style for the buttons
        Label(self.MainWindow, text='Rubiks Cube Solver', font=('Consolas', 40, 'bold'), bg='gray').pack()  # Shows a title 'Rubiks Cube Solver'
        timerbtn = ttk.Button(self.MainWindow, text='Timer', style='W.TButton')
        timerbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=CENTER)   # Creates a button and anchors it to the center
        solverbtn = ttk.Button(self.MainWindow, text='Solver', style='W.TButton')
        solverbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)  
        databasebtn = ttk.Button(self.MainWindow, text='Database', style='W.TButton', command=self.maindatabase)
        databasebtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)

        self.MainWindow.mainloop() # Don't forget the mainloop

    def maindatabase(self):
        self.MainWindow.withdraw()
        DataMenu = Toplevel(self.MainWindow)
        DataMenu.title('Database Viewer')  # Creates a window with the title 'Database Viewer' that is 640x480 and with a gray background
        DataMenu.geometry('640x480')
        DataMenu.config(bg='gray')
        Label(DataMenu, text='Database Viewer', font=('Consolas', 40, 'bold'), bg='gray').pack()  # Shows a title 'Database Viewer'
        searchbtn = ttk.Button(DataMenu, text='Search', style='W.TButton')
        searchbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)   # Creates a button and anchors it to the center
        fullbtn = ttk.Button(DataMenu, text='Full View', style='W.TButton')
        fullbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=CENTER)  
        backbtn = ttk.Button(DataMenu, text='Back', command=lambda:[DataMenu.destroy(), self.MainWindow.deiconify()])
        backbtn.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    rcs = RCS()
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issues mentioned by the other answer, there is another issue that if the user closes the *toplevel* window using the close button in the title bar, the main window will not be restored.  Use `.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", ...)` to fix this issue:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


def main():
    # use tk.Tk() instead of tk.Toplevel() for main/root window
    MainMenu = tk.Tk()
    MainMenu.title('Rubiks Cube Solver')  # Creates a window with the title 'Rubiks Cube Solver' that is 640x480 and with a gray background
    MainMenu.geometry('640x480')
    MainMenu.config(bg='gray')

    # create instance of ttk.Style() after creating the main window
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure('W.TButton', font=('Consolas', 25), foreground = 'black')  # Style for the buttons

    tk.Label(MainMenu, text='Rubiks Cube Solver', font=('Consolas', 40, 'bold'), bg='gray').pack()  # Shows a title 'Rubiks Cube Solver'

    timerbtn = ttk.Button(MainMenu, text='Timer', style='W.TButton')
    timerbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor=tk.CENTER)   # Creates a button and anchors it to the center

    solverbtn = ttk.Button(MainMenu, text='Solver', style='W.TButton')
    solverbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    databasebtn = ttk.Button(MainMenu, text='Database', style='W.TButton',
                             # pass MainWindow as an argument instead of using global variable
                             command=lambda:maindatabase(MainMenu))
    databasebtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    # need to call mainloop() for a tkinter application
    MainMenu.mainloop()

def maindatabase(MainMenu):
    # function to close the toplevel and
    # show back the main window
    def back():
        DataMenu.destroy()
        MainMenu.deiconify()
        MainMenu.lift()

    MainMenu.withdraw()
    DataMenu = tk.Toplevel(MainMenu)
    DataMenu.title('Database Viewer')  # Creates a window with the title 'Database Viewer' that is 640x480 and with a gray background
    DataMenu.geometry('640x480')
    DataMenu.config(bg='gray')
    # make sure to restore root window when closing the toplevel
    # by any other ways
    DataMenu.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", back)

    tk.Label(DataMenu, text='Database Viewer', font=('Consolas', 40, 'bold'), bg='gray').pack()  # Shows a title 'Database Viewer'

    searchbtn = ttk.Button(DataMenu, text='Search', style='W.TButton')
    searchbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)   # Creates a button and anchors it to the center

    fullbtn = ttk.Button(DataMenu, text='Full View', style='W.TButton')
    fullbtn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    backbtn = ttk.Button(DataMenu, text='Back', command=back)
    backbtn.place(relx=0.9, rely=0.3, anchor=tk.CENTER)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```